# Stepper Motor NEMA23 and driver A4988 matching problem?

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am experimenting with a stepper motor NEMA23 with the following specifications:

Rated current: 2.8A/phase
Resistance/Phase: 0.9
Step Angle: 1.8
Rated Voltage: 2.5
Inductance/Phase: 2.5 mH
Holding Torque: 12.6 kg/cm
Rotor Inertia: 300 g/cm2

The driver i am using is a a4988 Polulu with 2Amps maximum current. The Vref is set to 0.66 so depending on the Rsense ( 0.05 ) the Imax is set to 1.65.

I have made the wiring, uploaded the code with a delay of 0.1 seconds but the motor won't move. I use a power supply set to 20V.

Since this is very hard to debug. Is this driver compatible with the motor? Or the max current of the driver is too low to move the motor?

Comment: You haven't told us the wiring, shown us the code, or explained why you're powering a Rated Voltage 2.5V motor with 20V. Too much guesswork.

Comment: Ah let me see. Hobbyist setpping motors and drivers usually have the same architecture and wiring. I agree it is hard to debug. I remember the first time I learnt how to drive a stepping motor, I studied tutorials and use a battery, a multi-meter, and by hand power the coil in sequence to watch the motor move step by step (it is as enjoyable as a newbie learning how to blink a LED). I also try to control the motor driver step by step. Yes, it is tedious, but then I learn at the bottom level. / to continue, ...

Comment: You might find some useful references in the following Q&A: (1) Using L293D Motor Driver to Control Bipolar Stepping Motor 28BYJ48
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97975/controlling-28byj48-bipolar-convert-with-l293d-ic/97976#97976

Comment: Well i am just asking if it is theoretically possible. Brian Drummond, in my understanding, and from what i have read on the internet. I can feed my motor much more voltage than the rated one. Tho i must not overpass the rated curent. Since i have a A4988 with 2A max current i don t worry about the rated voltage.

Comment: @BrianDrummond if you take a little time to study stepper driving schemes you'll find that using several times the coil rated voltage to feed a chopping driver is just about obligatory for decent performance in a *motion* (vs simple slow positioning) application.  Motors aren't wound with low voltage coils because the makers expect low voltages will be used; rather they are wound that way to keep inductance down and let moderate voltages into a chopper drive achieve high step rates.

Comment: While this motor may be a bit much for a small IC driver; I'd expect *some* movement especially unloaded even if some sort of protection limit prevents rated current from being achieved, so my immediate guess is a *configuration* or *usage* problem.  Double check all of the inputs.  Look at the outputs with a scope.  If you really want to get maximum performance from this motor you will need a better driver, but first you need to understand what exactly is wrong with the setup.

Comment: @Chris : Absolutely true : and as the A4988 seems to be such a controller (I mistakenly thought it was an L293 style) I stand corrected on that point.

Comment: Ok, so i was finally able to move it. It was a soldering problem. It works just fine with the delay is about 0.1 s. As i decrease the time between pulses, the motor "misfires" can t move, it will move only if i help it. Meanwhile the a4988 getting hot as hell.